# DocumentProvider doesn't have permission to own ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-database, document-provider

My Application Has 2 types of provider

- [DocumentProvider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider) ( DP )is exported="true" required by the specs
- [ContentProvider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers) (CP)is exported="false" required by the security

Basic communication flow is 3rd Application asks DP for some info and DP ask CP for this info and return info to 3rd application.

Lets assume we use Microsoft Word/Excel to fetch some data from DocumentProvider. This is the scheme of the flow of communication between applications:

**Word  < ------- >  Document Provider  < ---- error here ---- > ContentProvider**

The issue is that DocumentProvider doesn't have access to its own ContentProvider. I mean that DP and CP are inside 1 application but they run in different processes.

The error is:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.app.name.provider.DataBaseContentProvider uri content://com.app.name.db.provider/files/innnerFiles/151515 from pid=6655, uid=10042 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission
```

DP:

```
<provider
        android:name="com.app.name.provider.DocProvider"
        android:authorities="com.app.name.provider.DocProvider"
        android:exported="true"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.action.DOCUMENTS_PROVIDER" />
        </intent-filter>
</provider>
```

CP:

```
<provider
    android:name="com.app.name.provider.DBProvider"
    android:authorities="com.app.name.provider.DBProvider"
    android:exported="false" />
```

Comment: Maybe you should add this <provider android:name="com.activeandroid.content.ContentProvider" android:authorities="your.package.name" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" /> in your Manifest file

Comment: @tm13 Why do I need it ? The com.activeandroid.content.ContentProvider is custom provider. I don't even know what it is..

Comment: Have you seen this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider#Permissions

Comment: @aminography Yes I've seen it. I use it as a temporary solution. Granting a permission to package opens Access to whole ContentProvider. I don't need to open access. I just need my data from my CP in my DP!

Answer (score 0):

The attribute

```
android:authority
```

attribute, which is your package name 
in this example,

```
com.app.name.provider.documents
```

the type of content provider (documents)

[Custom document provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/create-document-provider)

Answer (score 0):

Answering to this question needs more information including source codes.

However, According to [developer's doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/grant-uri-permission-element):

> Granting permission is a way of enabling clients of the provider that don't normally have permission to access its data to overcome that restriction on a one-time basis.

by adding [`grant-uri-permission`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/grant-uri-permission-element) element to the `DocProvider`'s manifest declaration, it can make a granted access to the specific `uri`s and the problem may solve.

```
<provider
    android:name="com.app.name.provider.DocProvider"
    android:authorities="com.app.name.provider.DocProvider"
    android:exported="true"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true"
    android:permission="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.content.action.DOCUMENTS_PROVIDER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <grant-uri-permission android:pathPrefix="content://com.app.name.db.provider" />

</provider>
```